# SQL: How to separate string values separated by commas?

Tags: sql, ms-access, csv, imdb

I'm trying to create a relational database of all the movies I have watched.

I used IMDb to rate the movies I've seen and used the site's export capability to get the data in a .csv file which I uploaded to Microsoft Access. However, the "Genre" column is a many-to-many relationship that I am hoping to turn into a one-to-many relationship.

I would like to have a table called `GENRE_ID` that assigns each genre a numerical ID. Then I'd have another table where each instance would have the `movie ID` ("const"), `line item number`, and `GENRE_ID`.

So it might look like:

```
const       line_item      MOVIE_ID
tt0068646       1             1   (if MOVIE_ID: 1 = "crime")
tt0068646       2             2   (if MOVIE_ID: 2 = "drama")
```

Here's a link to the image of my database's current state. Thank you so much for your help. This is a project I'm doing to learn more on my own time.

Comment: http://imgur.com/YWLiKFu

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you want to do with this database and how you want to report on it.  Wraith's answer makes sense, until you want to get a report by movie title with all genre's listed next to it, and then it turns into a transposition query and gets messy.  So you need to figure out what your primary concern is before you can determine the best way to store the data.

Comment: I eventually want to be able to use Excel's regression and correlation equations to find relationships between the type of movies I watch, the rating I give those movies, and the rating that the movie receives on IMDb. I guess I could just leave "genre" out of my model, but I'm interested in solving this problem on the database. I am looking for a query to write to automate this process. I agree that I don't want to have the same number of instances as the number of genres that a movie has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes on a way to a solution.

A table of genres

```
ID  Genre
1   Action
2   Adventure
3   Thriller
4   War
```

An import table

```
Const   GenreList
tt00    Action, Adventure, Thriller, War
```

A query

```
SELECT ti.Const, ti.GenreList, tg.Genre
FROM Imports as ti, Genres as tg
WHERE ti.GenreList Like "*" & tg.Genre & "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you  have a one-to-many relationship, you should use a table for that relationship
In your case, I would recommend to have 3 table:

1. Film table : contains information like your current table ,except Genres
2. Genre table : contains (at least) Id and Name
3. Film_Genre table : contains Film_Id, GenreId.

For example

In your genre table, your data would be

```
row 1: Id =1 , Name = "Crime"   
row 2: Id = 2, Name = drama,
```

and so on

your Film_Genre table would be something like:

```
row1: Film_Id = tt0068646, GenreId = 1,
row2: Film_Id = tt0068646, GenreId = 2
row3: Film_Id = tt0082971, GenreId = 2
```

and so on
(I supposed that you use "const" column as Id of Film table, if not, you should have your own Id)

Of course, it take you a litte bit effort to transform your current database to this database.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That structure makes sense, but I guess my question is how would I do this without having to manually add each of these?